# How to color odd even for svg rect

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

I have a bar chart (`svg`) and need to color bars(`rect`s) with two colors. Is there any way to do it in CSS with **odd even**?

```css
.chart rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg class="chart" width="420" height="120">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <rect width="40" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="37" y="9.5" dy=".35em">4</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,20)">
    <rect width="80" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="77" y="9.5" dy=".35em">8</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,40)">
    <rect width="150" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="147" y="9.5" dy=".35em">15</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,60)">
    <rect width="160" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="157" y="9.5" dy=".35em">16</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,80)">
    <rect width="230" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="227" y="9.5" dy=".35em">23</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,100)">
    <rect width="420" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="417" y="9.5" dy=".35em">42</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: need to clarify your question

Comment: let's say you have 4 rect elements, and need to color two of them in blue two in red based on on the odd/even number of element

Comment: yes, thats simple to do with css, but we'd need more information, your mark up at least and a jsfiddle

Comment: it can possible but you need to create jsfiddle or update que with some code here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kLm55bcp/

Comment: I have something like this coded in d3..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `nth-child` selectors like below to apply the styles. Since the `rect` element is not a direct child of your `svg` element you cannot apply the `nth-child` selector directly on it. Instead, we have to select the odd/even `g` element and then style the `rect` element inside it accordingly.

```css
.chart g:nth-child(even) rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.chart g:nth-child(odd) rect {
  fill: red;
}
.chart text {
  fill: white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<svg class="chart" width="420" height="120">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <rect width="40" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="37" y="9.5" dy=".35em">4</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,20)">
    <rect width="80" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="77" y="9.5" dy=".35em">8</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,40)">
    <rect width="150" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="147" y="9.5" dy=".35em">15</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,60)">
    <rect width="160" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="157" y="9.5" dy=".35em">16</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,80)">
    <rect width="230" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="227" y="9.5" dy=".35em">23</text>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,100)">
    <rect width="420" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="417" y="9.5" dy=".35em">42</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks that's perfect!